# How do I iterate over a pyo3 PyObject in Rust?

Tags: rust, pyo3

I have a pre-imported module that I'm calling a method with python gil, something like the following.

```
Python::with_gil(|py| {
    let res = module.call_method1(py, "my_method", (arg1, arg2))?;
})
```

This returns the rust object PyObject, however what this returns is a python `list`. I want to iterate over this list to convert the internals into something I can use in Rust (it's a python list of Numpy arrays, I'm using the numpy/ndarray crates).

I'm a little confused as to how I'm meant to iterate over this. If I try `cast_as` to a `PyList`, I get the warning: `UnsafeCell<PyObject> cannot be shared between threads safely`. It seems `extract` does not work either.

How do I iterate over this PyObject? Thanks.

**Edit: Adding further details as requested**

The returned value from python is a `List[numpy.ndarray]` if you are using the python Typing system. As the lengths of each numpy array could be different, I cannot just convert it all into a numpy array in python and pass it through. An example output is below:

```py
[array([214.17725372, 192.78236675, 354.27965546, 389.84558392,
          0.99999297])]
```

What I've tried in Rust:

- `let pylist = res.cast_as::<PyList>(py)?;`

  Fails to compile with: `UnsafeCell<PyObject> cannot be shared between threads safely`.
- `let pylist = res.extract::<PyList>(py)?;`

  Fails to compile with: `the trait 'PyClass' is not implemented for 'PyList'`. Please note I have `use pyo3::prelude::*;` at the top.
- `let pyany = res.extract::<Vec<PyArray1<f64>>>(py)?;`

  Fails to compile with: `the trait bound 'Vec<PyArray<f64, Dim<[usize; 1]>>>: pyo3::FromPyObject<'_>' is not satisfied`. This PyArray is from the `numpy` crate.

Comment: Please share the code for what you've tried. Please include a minimal example including your python code.

Comment: Updated with more details. @PitaJ

Answer (score 0):

I see that you returning a list of `numpy` arrays with `dtype=float`. If you are open to using another dependency, there is [rust-numpy](https://github.com/PyO3/rust-numpy) which lets you map `numpy` arrays to `ndarrays` in Rust.

`ndarrays` have a `.to_vec()` method to convert to standard Rust containers.

In your case you could do the following (this is not tested):

```
use numpy::PyArray1;
use pyo3::{types::IntoPyDict, PyResult, Python};

Python::with_gil(|py| {
    let res: Vec<&PyArray1<f32>> = module // <-- Notice the return type
                                 .call_method1(py, "my_method", (arg1, arg2))?
                                 .extract()?; // <--  Notice the extract
})
```

Mappings between Python and Rust types can be found [here](https://pyo3.rs/latest/conversions/tables.html). You can then use the `res` to do further computations.

```
println!("I just got a numpy array from python {:?}", res[0]);
println!("I converted that to a vector here: {:?}", res[0].to_vec());
```